# Windows App - Facebook Login Windows Store SID for testing

Tags: c#, facebook, windows

I'm new on developing an application on Windows. I want to integrate a Facebook login button for my user to login. However, when I create the app in Facebook Developer console, it ask for the **Windows Store SID**. My app is still in developing and what I should put there? Please help me. If you can, please provide a step by step solution to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri().ToString();` gets SID